# Popen remote commands

Tags: python

Looking to run the command: ssh user@some_host "echo 'some_sql' | /usr/bin/mysql -u some_args"

How would I do this using Popen?

```
p1 = sp.Popen(["ssh", "user@some_host", "echo \"%s\"" % sql], stdout=sp.PIPE)
p2 = sp.Popen(["/usr/bin/mysql", "-u some_args"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Returns "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" since it's looking for /usr/bin/mysql on the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps combining it all into a single command?

```
p1 = sp.Popen(["ssh", "user@some_host", "echo \"%s\" | mysql -u ..." % sql], stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use Popen at all; use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/) instead

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect('www.somehost.com', username='user')
ssh_client.exec_command(' "echo 'some_sql' | /usr/bin/mysql -u some_args"')
```

Comment: Yes, or `Pexpect` is another easy to use solution

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess` always runs commands on the local machine. If you want to run commands over SSH, you'll need to pass the commands as input to your `ssh` process via stdin, or as an argument when you start ssh.

A better idea, however, might be to use a library that's designed for running remote commands like [`fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.1/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In response to Amber, the OP says he is trying to run the command :

ssh user@some_host "echo 'some_sql' | /usr/bin/mysql -u some_args"

So he is clearly, passing the commands as "an argument when you start ssh".